# Why does the image disappear when height or width applied in percent?

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, expo

I have an image which I want to display inside a modal. I am using Image from expo-image to display the image inside modal. However, my image disappears when I apply the height or width in percent. I have tried getting dimensions and then multiplying it but that doesn't work either.

It only works if I write the style like this:

```
style={{
width: 350,
height:600,
}}
```

But if I write it that way then image becomes scrollable on smaller screens. When screen size is changed I want image to readjust to that specific screen without getting zoomed in or becoming scrollable.

Below is my full code:

```
  import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const ScreenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const ScreenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

const PromoModal = ({ showPromoModal, setShowPromoModal, bannerData }) => {
  console.log("Banner Data", bannerData?.[0]?.imageUrl);
  const {id, imageUrl, message} = bannerData?.[0]
  const onModalClose = () => {
    // useBannerStore.setState({bannerId: id})
    setShowPromoModal(false);
  };

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={showPromoModal} onClose={onModalClose} size="full">
      <Modal.Content maxH='70%' maxWidth='90%' style={{ width: "90%" }}>
        <Modal.CloseButton
          position="absolute"
          top={0}
          right={2}
          marginBottom={12}
        />
        <Modal.Body >
          {/* <Text style={{ textAlign: "center" }} fontSize="md" mt={3} fontWeight={500}>
            {message}
          </Text> */}
          <Image
            // source={imageUrl}
            // source={{ uri: 'https://www.aitoolsbazzar.com/placeholder/300x600/661d1d/1efff1/HELLO THIS IS PROMOTIONAL BANNER/jpeg' }}

            source= {require('../assets/images/new.jpg')}
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              width: 300,
              height: 600,
              alignSelf:'center',
              marginTop:0,
              resizeMode:'contain',
            }}
          />
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal.Content>
    </Modal>
  );
};
```

Comment: Right click your image, and look at what _actual_ CSS values are getting set, because your 350 and 600 don't stay that, they get the `px` unit added to them. Values with units are strings, so as long as you set them as `width: "10%", height: "10%"`, that should work just fine. _Provided_ that your src url is a valid image.

Comment: it is a valid image, its showing up but not with percentage

Comment: Then it's time for that age-old practice: [debugging](https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging). Set your width and height to strings with percentages, and look at what actual content is getting generated (and then of course add that information to your post so that folks know what your device is doing, while using those new clues to keep investigating, yourself)